# FileSystem uploading files vs HTTP Request in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I don't see difference between `File System uploading files` and simple `HTTP Request`.
So I can upload file through these methods, but which is the best to use and when?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? What do you mean by "File System uploading files" ?

Comment: I mean this: `https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all they do not exclude each other. Because you take the file from the [Http request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files) and use [Laravel Flysystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem) to upload it to Amazon S3 or Dropbox, but you can also store it locally as with the Request move method. The advantage is that when you use Filesystem you can easily switch the location for saving the files.

So, if you need only local storage you can use Http Request without a problem, otherwise, for cloud storage, I wold advise to use the Filesystem.

Comment: Thank you for extended answer, so do you recommend to use Http Requesti for uploading files outside?

Comment: I recommend Filesystem to upload files outside of your local storage.

Comment: How can I locate file in `public` directory?